# Dropdown menu not dropping down in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to bootstrap and i'm trying to add a header navbar dropdown. Looking at tutorials and examples I've come up with this which I though would work but doesn't.

Here is the coding (the site is build in rails)

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
    <%= link_to "Guidir", root_path, id: "logo" %>
     </div>
    <nav>
      <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
      <ul>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Notifications", user_user_notifications_path(current_user) %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Mailbox", user_conversations_path(current_user) %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in/ Signup", login_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

I'm not the greatest with bootstrap but from looking up the problem and other examples of dropdowns they all seems to work and be similar coding. I'm not sure why mine wont work.

Comment: do you add `jquery` and `bootstrap` js to your page?? i think you should change `ul` to `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`

Comment: See here Bootstrap dropdown: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Comment: @shayanypn might be a jquery problem, it only seems to work in google chrome

Comment: @user3234020 u check your pure html with jquery version "1.11.3" and bootstrap library on chrome and firefox,and it works fine.

Comment: @shayanypn cant see anywhere it specifically stated the jquery and bootstrap version

Comment: Turnout I had Jquery disabled on my browsers and forgot to change it back